# Parse Integer from Buffer

Tags: node.js, integer, buffer

I created this function to parse a Integer from a Buffer:

```
var makeInt = function(b1, b2, b3, b4) {
    return ((b1 <<  0) & 0x000000FF) +   
           ((b2 <<  8) & 0x0000FF00) + 
           ((b3 << 16) & 0x00FF0000) + 
           ((b4 << 24) & 0xFF000000);
}
```

From a buffer I read the Integer like that:

```
var buffer = new Buffer([0,0,15,47,0,0,0,64,0,0])

console.log(makeInt(buffer[3],buffer[2],buffer[1],buffer[0]))

=> 3887
```

**What's the official Buffer function from https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html that does the same like my `makeInt` function?**

I tried https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuintbe_offset_bytelength_noassert

But `buf.readUIntLE(offset, byteLength[, noAssert])` returns:

```
buffer.readUIntLE(0, 3)

=> 983040
```

Why is it not returning `3887 != 983040`?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use 4 bites, but passed 3. There are two ways to store number - little-endian and big-endian. It seems your code realized big-endian.

```
var buffer = new Buffer([0,0,15,47,0,0,0,64,0,0]);
console.log(buffer.readUIntBE(0, 4));
```

Comment: Works, Thanks a lot!